# fixed navbar. How to manage its horizontal behavior properly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a fixed navbar in my website but I'm experiencing some problem with its horizontal behavior.

If I don't make it "responsive", and you have a window large enough, everything is fine:
[image]

BUT if I try to shrink my window, all the content below is scrollable, except my navbar that will have the rightmost items hidden:
[image]

This is not really the behavior I want by it! I would simply like to have an access to all my navbar's elements.

Next, I tried to use a responsive layout, just for my fixed navbar. Now everything seems to be fine when I shrink the window:
[image]

BUT if I scroll my content horizontally, my navbar appears to be quite antiaesthetic as you can see here:
[image]

so, my question is: is there a way to get better the responsive layout? I was thinking about a javascript that move my navbar when in "shrink mode". Is there already a tested solution for it?
Otherwise: is there a solution for the non-responsive, fixed navbar?

Thanks!

---

update: here is my code

```
<div id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner collapsed">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="http://www.lifeparticipation.org/liquid.html" target="_blank">
        <div><img class="logo" id="logo" src="styles/imgs/logo.png"></div>
      </a>      

      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <% if(typeof userName === "undefined"){ %>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user accedi"></i> Accedi <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="loginFacebook"><span class="facebook">&nbsp;</span>facebook</a></li>                 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <% } else{ %>                                        
        <li class="dropdown" style="">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style=""><img style="height: 30px" class="img-rounded" src="<%=userPicURL %>" style=""> <%=userName %> <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 13px; padding-top: 0px;"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="logout"><i class="icon-off"></i> Esci</a></li>                 
            </ul>
        </li>        
        <% } %>                             
      </ul><!-- <ul class="nav pull-right"> -->          
      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Museo</a></li> 
        </ul>        
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">   
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="styles/imgs/flags/it.png"> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/imgs/flags/it.png"> Italiano</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/imgs/flags/es.png"> Castellano</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/imgs/flags/galicia.png"> Galego</a></li>                    
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/imgs/flags/pt.png"> Português europeu</a></li>                                        
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="styles/imgs/flags/eu.png"> English</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>                                        
        </ul>
      </div><!--<div class="nav-collapse collapse">--> 
    </div><!--<div class="container">-->
  </div>
</div>
```

And these two images depicts a little bit better what happens with a responsive navbar and a non-responsive content:

[image: without scrolling. Everything seems to be OK]

[image: as soon as you scroll horizontally, you notice this anti aesthetic behavior. What a pain in the buns!]

a JSFiddle that tries to reproduce the problem is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bertuz/PRVt6/)

Comment: Overall `position:fixed` does not have great support on mobile. Only the newest phones handle it to meet the expectations. Check out jquery-mobile -- it has neat header/footer support.

Comment: @Mikhail The fact is that I'm on a mac! You don't have to shrink so much to experience those problems

Comment: @Amicable I compiled my own bootstrap css here [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) by unticking all the responsive behaviors, except for the navbar. Next, I used the .js and .css generated without tweaking them.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? The Bootstrap navbar isn't supposed to behave like it appears in the last image.

Comment: @Skelly I put it in my question. Are you sure it shouldn't behave like that? It's a blend of responsive and non-responsive elements! I mean, under that navbar there's a lot of content in a fixed row-and-span divs. And because of that, the navbar shrinks itself, but the content not, generating a navbar with the same width of the window, but keeping the content below the navbar at the same width.

Comment: @Skelly I've just added two images along with the code in order to understand the problem better. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm wondering what the wide content is that's causing the horizontal scrolling. Can you recreate the problem on Bootply.com or JSFiddle?

Comment: Yup, good idea! I'll do it

Comment: @Skelly you can find the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bertuz/PRVt6/). Notice I used some external resource: my bootstrap .js and .css (try to take a look to them, even though I've never modified them!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `bootstrap-responsive.css` for the responsive navbar to work properly.

Here is an update using the combined Bootstrap CSS from BootstrapCDN: http://jsfiddle.net/PRVt6/1/

Comment: I've customized my own bootstrap, so I think everything I need should be in. I've tried both versions with a responsive navbar and without. The results are the ones I posted in the original question.
P.S. If I resize the window, the navbar resizes itself properly. The problem is that anti aesthetic right space if I scroll horizonatally. Check out the fiddle I created to understand what the problem really is :-). It uses a customized bootstrap, where only the navbar should be responsive.

Comment: Moreover, that's NOT the behavior I want for my content! I only want my navbar to be responsive, whereas the rest should be static-fixed. Let's say it's a blend choice

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I did it.

I simply overflowed a css statement of my bootstrap responsive css:

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
}
```

now the navbar behaves the way I want. Of course there's a small catch: now when I expand my collapsed navbar, it covers a part of my normal flow of the page, but that's ok for me because I'm designing my website just for quite big screen sizes (tablets, pcs and so on).
If anyone finds a smarter, better solution I'll be glad to see it :-)